# How to use a series of drop down list to display data from mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, menu

needing some advice.

I am wanting to include 4 drop down lists on a website, which all contain data from different fields in a mysql table.

I then want to be able to press a submit button and display the required data on a webpage.

I am having trouble with knowing what programming language to use and also finding it difficult to find any tutorials.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to query data from a database using PHP? Do you know how to write a `<select>` element in HTML? Do you know how to cobble together HTML dynamically using PHP? Combine all of those.

Comment: So, this unfortunately falls under 'not asking a specific question' and 'having an ambiguous answer'. You should probably learn first (and ask questions about) how to display drop downs, and submit that as a form (via html). Then you'll need to populate those dropdowns with some scripting or web app language. But you're talking about many steps, and since you're starting with nothing, it's outside the scope of what StackOverflow is about.

Comment: It's all good. :) Someone wrote out an example anyway, I see!

Answer (score 1):

You mean a HTML dropdown list or just a select dropdown in a form?

If you mean a select dropdown in a form you could do something like this:

```
<?PHP

$query = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM table ORDER BY value ASC") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_num_rows($result);

// If no results have been found or when table is empty?
if ($result == 0) {

    echo 'No results have been found.';

} else {

    // Display form
    echo '<form name="form" method="post" action="your_result.php">';
    echo '<select name="list" id="lists">';

    // Fetch results from database and list in the select box
    while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        echo '<option id="'.$fetch['value'].'">'.$fetch['value'].'</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>';
    echo '</form>';

}

?>
```

And then in your_result.php you should fetch the data from your MySQL database based on value from the (when you fetch use mysql_real_escape_string):

```
<?PHP $_POST['list']; ?>
```

You could also do everything in just one file, but thats up to you. Try to use google, there are dozens of tutorials out there.